# GCP GCE F1-micro not free?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a GCE f1-micro in GCP. It should be free according to: [GCP Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#compute-engine)

and following the tutorial: [How to set up a free micro VPS on Google Cloud Platform](https://medium.com/@hbmy289/how-to-set-up-a-free-micro-vps-on-google-cloud-platform-bddee893ac09)

However it does not seem to be free. The pricing calculator set beside is showing the message:

> $4.28 monthly estimate

What I am missing? thanks

Comment: Don't forget to factor in network egress bandwidth pricing. This is not part of the Free Tier discounts and is a separate pricing item in the pricing calculator.

Comment: Things have changed, it's now "1 non-preemptible e2-micro VM instance per month".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's f1-micro is always free up to 720 hours (1 month)** in the supported regions. GCP still shows you the cost per hour, because GCP doesn't yet know how many hours you're going to use. If you use more than 720 hours, it will begin charging you at that rate.

> Your Always Free f1-micro instance limit is by time, not by instance. Each month, eligible use of all of your f1-micro instances is free until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the current month.

Comment: thanks. I missed to read the message on the side "Your first 720 hours of f1-micro instance usage are free this month."

Comment: so if u just have 1 instance than is it free the entire month, every month?

Comment: @bluejayke Yes, although there may be other costs which are not full discounted - for example, if you go above 1GB/month regular outbound transit to most continents.

Comment: @green didn't know there was a bandwidth limit, does it also apply to us or is that unlimited?

Comment: @bluejayke The server is free, the network resources are not - or at least not fully. A dynamic IP attached to the machine is fully discounted, at this time. But if you send more than 1GB of data to non-Google locations in the Americas, say, it is likely to cost you (but Europe and Asia each get 1GB as well). If you send *any* to China or Australia it will cost you; although they may round to the nearest cent. This can be a problem if you get a bunch of traffic that you have not firewalled off, even if all you do is respond with a 404 or similar. Inbound won't cost you, but any responses may.

Comment: GCP does have extensive reporting capabilities and it is possible to drill down to specfic SKUs that they are charging to identify costs. You can also do things like serve data from your instance via App Engine, since that gets 1GB/day total, and traffic between it and a Compute instance is free (since they are both Google properties).

Comment: It's now "1 non-preemptible e2-micro VM instance per month" and I could not see the "Your first 720 hours are free" message.

Answer (score 6):

Sicne this was answered, the free instance type is now an e2-micro, not an f1-micro, but this answer should otherwise still hold.

---

A single free tier qualified (e.g. e2-micro) instance, running for an entire month, given certain constraints, should be free, yes.

2 things might be at play here for your estimate:

When using the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator), to ensure the free tier limits are accounted for, make sure you check the "Include Always Free usage in my estimate" box (note that this checkbox only appears if you have selected a valid "always free" configuration):

[image: free tier box]

The GCP pricing calculator does not automatically include disk in the estimate, but it would also account for the free tier for disk usage in a similar way, when it is added to the estimate.

That said, you appear to be referring to the estimate that shows up on the "Create an instance" page.  This estimate does not account for the free tier, and additionally includes the cost the persistent disk that you have requested (also without accounting for the free tier).  However, if you see the message "Your first 720 hours of f1-micro instance usage are free this month." above that estimate, the instance (but possibly not including the disk if it is, for example, larger than 30GB) should qualify for the free tier (subject to your other usage, of course).

Second, the [always free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits) for an f1-micro is only in one of three US regions: `us-west1`, `us-central1`, or `us-east1`.  Make sure you have selected one of those regions.

Comment: actually it is ok, I missed to read the message on the side "Your first 720 hours of f1-micro instance usage are free this month."

Comment: 3.88 doesn't include the HDD cost, which is also free up to 30GB

Comment: Yup. There are two different places you can see a pricing estimate.  I've extended my answer as it looks like @toto' was referring to the estimate on the instance creation page.

Comment: Things have changed, it's now "1 non-preemptible e2-micro VM instance per month" and the above checkbox no longer appears to be visible. unless I missed it.